# Performance comparaison betwen ff4j and togglz

Tags: performance, toggle, togglz, ff4j

We're working on a project , and we want to use some toggling feature tool like ff4j or togglz but we have a real constraints about performances, i mean we really need a tool with the less time of execution , i've checked a little bit ff4j and togglz but i don't know what is best for this solution, or may be if you know some other tools.

**Context of project:** its a netflix microservices architecture, so we have eureka,ribbon,zuul and microservices.

otherwise , if you have another solution , may be develop a sidecar please give me some ideas.

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer : I created FF4j, as such I won't give you answer relative to performance comparison. I will provide architecture design principles.*

Microservices means distributed architecture so you will have to store the state of your features in a **common persistence storage** (DB).

The *cost* of feature toggle framework won't be time to evaluate the feature state predicate (it is a simple condition) it will be the **time to access the data** from the persistence storage.

**FF4j** provides support for both REDIS and CONSUL:

- Redis seems a good candidate as very fast for put/get and distribute.
- Consul is also a good idea in distributed microservice : it provides a key-value store.
- Eureka may does the same, I don't know, ff4j does not have store for it yet.

If you have to store your features in a slower DB such as SQL-Like then you might consider to use caching. FF4j provides some `cacheProxy` to handle such use cases.

Other Considerations :

- Put the administration console only in a backend application not on each microservices (security + performance overhead)
- Feature Toggle can do more with Configuration Management and monitoring.

You may want to have a look at this [15min talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6PtQtOYhus) exactly on that subject. LIVE DEMO starting at [7:10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6PtQtOYhus&feature=youtu.be&t=430)

and [related github repository](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j-samples/tree/master/ff4j-voxxeddays-ticino-2018) for sample with Spring-Cloud

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but we're already working with caching service , the question is more related to the time that the request is taking to be created ( the tcp/ip request) , can't we do something about it ?

Comment: SIde-note, LDAP is "database" meant to be blazingly fast at reading... It was build for similar goal, as feature toggle storage.